# DD-Block resizes images

Tags: theming

I'm developing a website in Drupal 6, and I've employed [Dynamic Display Block](http://drupal.org/project/ddblock) for a slideshow that displays in a panel.

Unfortunately, even though the images show in the slideshow, they are not rendered in their full size as I described in the configuration page of the Dynamic Display Block settings.

I used firebug, and I realised that a class called `ddblock-processed` has been added which is the cause of the issue i'm facing, as it has different dimensions compared to the one I specified.

I've tried overriding that effect in the style sheet - css, but to no avail.

Someone should kindly help me hack this stuff under the hood.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ddblock-processed` class is added to your div when the Javascript event is attached to it by Drupal. This is normal behavior, but it shouldn't be too hard to override the style with CSS.

To show you a simple example of CSS overrides (even though this is considered an inefficient selector, it doesn't matter too much in cases such as yours):

If on the original style, the CSS is declared as follows:

```
.ddblock-processed {
  width: 100px;
}
```

You can easily override it in your own stylesheet by including the "parent" element in the CSS selector. So if `ddblock-processed` div's parent is a div with an ID of `myregion` then doing this will override it:

```
div.ddblock-processed {
  width: 200px;
}

/* OR */

#myregion .ddblock-processed {
  width: 200px;
}

/* OR */

body .ddblock-processed {
  width: 200px;
}

/* OR */

div .ddblock-processed {
  width: 200px;
}
```

This is called [CSS specificity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=0&oq=CSS%20speci&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20specificity) if you want to read up about it.

Comment: '#ddblock-1.ddblock-contents .ddblock-content .ddblock-container img.ddblock-processed {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 612px;
}`

Comment: That's a really long selector, but simply adding `body` at the very front of that selector should let you override this one you posted: `body #ddblock-1.ddblock-contents .ddblock-content .ddblock-container img.ddblock-processed { height: 400px; overflow: hidden; width: 612px; }`. It's ugly and it's not nice, but if you have modules that have CSS like that then you have to do things like this sometimes.

Comment: still didn't work. you may want to visit the website [link](http://steponeestate.com) which is in its very basic stage.

If you use firebug tool or any other, you would see that I've added css declaration, and yet nothing happens.

I believe the Javascript overwrites or supersedes this declaration.

Thank you.

Comment: put `!important` after the width height like so: `width: 612px!important;`. I've just installed DDBlock and checked it out, if you go to the Block's Configure page, there's width and height settings there too. Have you tried modifying them? You can also use `imagecache.module` to display images in a certain size which is pretty cool.

Comment: I've added the !important to the css declaration, and it didn't take any effect, unfortunately. All the same, I did modify the width and height in the settings of the DDBlock module and that should have done the work, since it's not my first time using it.

Comment: I can now see the !important and I can see that the dimensions of <img>'s are 612x400 (check the "Layout" tab on your firebug), I think it's working. But looking at your original image files, all of them are 600x388 sizes, maybe this Module prevents upscaling of images somehow?

Comment: Well, I did use the imagecache and I have control over it with respect to what I want.

Thank you for your assistance.

:)

Comment: oh right, then you should "Allow Upscaling" on your Imagecache preset settings perhaps